# puma:restart cap production deploy service not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, puma

Rails 7.0.4
Puma 6.0

I am so close to getting `cap production deploy` to work in production but I'm stuck on puma:restart

I have an active service on the server

```
deploy@reports:~/apps/R7-reporting-2022/current$ sudo systemctl status R7-reporting-2022_puma_production.service
[sudo] password for deploy:
● R7-reporting-2022_puma_production.service - Puma HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/R7-reporting-2022_puma_production.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-11-06 19:24:32 UTC; 1h 3min ago
Main PID: 612 (puma)
Tasks: 10 (limit: 4575)
Memory: 177.7M
CPU: 2.258s
CGroup: /system.slice/R7-reporting-2022_puma_production.service
└─612 "puma 6.0.0 (unix:///home/deploy/apps/R7-reporting-2022/shared/tmp/sockets/R7-reporting-2022-puma.sock)" "" "" "" "" "" ">

Nov 06 19:24:32 reports systemd[1]: Started Puma HTTP Server.
```

When I run bundle exec cap production deploy I get the following error

```
00:24 puma:restart
01 /bin/systemctl --user restart R7-reporting-2022_puma_production
01 Failed to restart R7-reporting-2022_puma_production.service: Unit R7-reporting-2022_puma_production.service not found.
```

I'm wondering if the `--user` part of the command is what's causing the issue?

after further testing I can run the command without `--user` flag on the server.

`/usr/bin/env /bin/systemctl restart R7-reporting-2022_puma_production`

````
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  user (user)
 2.  deploy user,,, (deploy)
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): 2
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===```
````

Answer (score 0):

I switched from puma to passenger using the following guide. Great instructions, simple implementation. Props to the writer.

[Rails Deploy on Ubuntu using Capistrano](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/22.04)